# HttpClient authenticating to Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Jenkins 1.515 server.  This is configured to delegate access control to the servlet container (stand-alone Tomcat 6). I'm using matrix-based security and have ticked the boxes for every action for user 'foo'.
I'm trying to use HttpClient (4.2.3) to query the build status.  Using the basic HttpClient authentication, so far I have:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("dev.mycompany.com", 80), 
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("foo", "bar"));

    try {

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://dev.mycompany.com/jenkins/rssLatest");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println(responseBody);

    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

when this executes, the result is:

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
```

Now, I have tried many different 'examples' found via Google of different methods to authenticate using HttpClient, but all of them result in either the same error above, or an 'Internal Server Error'.  
I need to work out exactly what procedure to use to authenticate using HttpClient 4 against this Jenkins instance.

Comment: In your Jenkins Configuration, is the `Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits` option enabled?

Comment: 'Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits' box is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I could find on Java approaches to authenticate directly, I worked out   that wget could work using 'Basic' Authorization, and then I used HttpClient to mimic the same request/response headers.  This is not a recommended approach that I could find, but it worked for me. eg:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://dev.mycompany.com/jenkins/rssLatest?token=MYTOKEN");
            httpget.setHeader("Host", "dev.mycompany.com");
            httpget.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic USERNAMEandMYTOKENbase64ENCRYPTED=" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Jenkins returns the error 403 (FORBIDDEN) when you're not logged in but HttpClient expects the error 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) in [TargetAuthenticationStrategy](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/TargetAuthenticationStrategy.java). Therefore, HttpClient never notices that Jenkins is asking for the password.

One way to fix this is to use "Preemptive authentication" described here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

That will do the same as you did: Always add the "Authorization" header to the request.

Copy of the code example:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = <...>

HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80, "http");
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

// Create AuthCache instance
AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
// Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

// Add AuthCache to the execution context
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
context.setAuthCache(authCache);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(
            targetHost, httpget, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
}
```